# Why is delete[] not equivalent to calling delete for each element in C++?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Assuming I created an array in the heap:

```
int* a = new int[10];
```

Why is this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        delete (a + i);
}
```

not equivalent to `delete[] a;`? Attempting to call `delete` for any pointer to an element in `a` results in an memory access violation.

What excactly is the difference?

Comment: show the whole code

Comment: Because that's the way it works.

Comment: The pointer you give to `delete` has to be a pointer that was returned by `new`. You only got `a`, not `a+1`, `a+2`, etc.

Comment: @Swift It's undefined behavior to try to delete a pointer that was not returned by `new`.

Comment: @Barmar UB here is actually use `delete` on pointer returned by `new[]`.

Comment: On my platform, `malloc`, `new`, and `new[]` are in separate heaps.  Each has very different bookkeeping information (metadata).  So calling `delete` on something made by `new[]` crashes the application.  Would you consider that a difference?

Comment: Yes, thanks to all of you. Those were the kind of answers I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointer you give to `delete` has to be a pointer that was returned by `new`. Furthermore, if you use `new[]` to allocate the object, you have to use `delete[]` to delete it.

In many implementations, the metadata that holds information about an allocation (e.g. the size of the allocation) is stored in the memory just before the allocation. So when you pass a pointer to `delete`, it looks in the preceding memory locations to find this information. When you allocate an array, there's only one of these metadata blocks for the entire allocation. If you try to delete an element inside the array, there won't be any metadata before it, so it won't know how much memory to free.

Answer (score 2):

No. Array-type storage is what amounts to contains *one* object , for which storage  was allocated and it should be deallocated accordingly.

From 8.3.4 New

> If the allocated type is a non-array type, the allocation function’s
>   name is operator new and the deallocation function’s name is operator
>   delete. If the allocated type is an array type, the allocation
>   function’s name is operator new[] and the deallocation function’s name
>   is operator delete[].

Pointer returned by `new` expression should be deallocated by delete. `new[]` expression returns pointer to first element of array and  to deallocate array  you should use only `delete[]` operator. Other combinations yield UB and the use delete on element of array is UB.

Answer (score 0):

`new int[10]` allocates **one** block of memory with enough room for ten objects of type `int`. When you're done with that memory block you need to release it; you do that with `delete []`, which tells the runtime system that you're finished with that **one** block of memory.

That's the simple case. When you allocate memory for a type that has a non-trivial destructor, the compiler has to generate code to destroy each of the array elements. In that case, `new T[10]` allocates **one** block of memory with enough room for ten objects of type `T`, and it **creates** those ten objects using the default constructor. When you're done what that memory block you need to release it; you do that with `delete []`, which calls the destructor for each of the ten elements, then tells the runtime system that you're finished with that **one** block of memory.